# Get position of other GameObject with a certain shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

If I have shader **X** and shader **Y**, how could shader **Y** get the world positions of all `gameObjects` with shader **X**?

Due to my restrictions, I can't use any `MonoBehaviours` for this. Only shaders.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

They cannot, shaders can't communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

Shaders are executed as part of the rendering pipeline on the GPU, while Unity's game logic is on the CPU. So not only are shaders executed outside of Unity, they're on an entirely separate piece of hardware.

You can find more details in this link :
[From unity answer][https://answers.unity.com/questions/456516/can-a-glsl-shader-fetch-gameobject-properties.html]